# GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_link_full: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (sinkpad)' failed

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, rhythmbox, gstreamer

It is not possible to extract Audio-CDs with **Rhythmbox**. When starting an Audio-CD extraction Rhythmbox prompts `Error transferring track. Internal data flow error`. Starting Rhythmbox in a terminal, the command line tells:

`(rhythmbox:2854): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_link_full: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (sinkpad)' failed`.

I have this problem since Xubuntu 16.4. On Xubuntu 14.4. I did not have this problem. On Xubuntu 14.4 I had a folder .gstreamer-0.10. I reinstalled libsgstreamer0.10-0, but this didn't solve the problem. I only understand that sink means output. Any ideas?